# Cannot use darknet / Yolo2 after installation (Python)

Tags: python, darkflow

I want to use `darkflow` / `Yolo2` according to the instructions from [github](https://github.com/thtrieu/darkflow)

After successful installation I'm not able to do anything. The flow command does not work and I cant load weights.

I am receiving the following warning:

> der befehl "flow" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder konnte nicht
>   gefunden werden (the command "flow" is written wrongly or could not be
>   found)

What I did:

```
-Started cmd
-changed working dir. to darkflow dir
-installed succesfully darkflow with command: pip install .
-tried to use the flow command but failed
```

Can someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I have to write the word 'python' infront of the 'flow' command. This seems to be necessary under windows.

Not working for me:

```
flow -h
```

Now working fine by using the python command infront of the flow command:

```
python flow -h
```

Example-Loading the weights and make a few predictions on sample Images:

```
>python flow --model cfg/tiny-yolo-voc.cfg --load bin/tiny-yolo-voc.weights
```

Comment: how did you get darkflow to build and populate bin directory?

Comment: Hello Tyler, I just followed the instructions at the darkflow github site : https://github.com/thtrieu/darkflow Which Problems do you have in detail?